# Непонятная реакция при использовании методов Win32_Process (WinForms)

Tags: c#, .net

Есть код вывода информации о процессах в массив:

```
var process = new StringBuilder(); 
ManagementObjectSearcher searcherProc = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "Select Name, CommandLine From Win32_Process"); 
foreach (ManagementObject instance in searcherProc.Get()) 
{ 
process.AppendLine(string.Format("Процесс: {0}", instance["Name"])); 
} 
/*foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process winProc in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses()) 
{ 
processi.AppendLine(string.Format("Процесс: {0}, Имя: {1}.exe", winProc.Id, winProc.ProcessName, )); 
}*/ 
show_information(process.ToString());
```

Из методов работает только `Name`. При использовании  `Caption` или `OSName` компилятор выдает ошибку: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно исправить ошибку, или другими средствами языка вывести информацию о процессах (всех запущенных): Имя, ID, Путь, Память?

Comment: При чем тут компилятор? Ошибка происходит во время выполнения.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В своём запросе:

```sql
Select Name, CommandLine From Win32_Process
```

Вы выбираете только поля `Name` и `CommandLine`. Соответственно получить значения полей `Caption` и `OSName` вы не сможете - вы их попросту не выбирали.

В внутреннем исключении об этом и сказано, но вы в него видимо не заглядывали.

Просто добавьте в запрос необходимые поля.

---

Без WMI информацию указанную вами информацию можно было бы получить, например, перебрав Process.GetProcesses():

```c#
var info = from process in Process.GetProcesses()
           select new { process.ProcessName, process.Id, process.WorkingSet64};
```

Но к сожалению, информацию о коммандной строке вы так не получите - если она нужна, то всё же придется прибегнуть к помощи WMI.

Comment: Точно, я как то не обратил на это внимание. Большое спасибо за скорую помощь :)